# Why does my code for removing the even numbers from the beginning of a list not work?

Tags: python-3.x, list, error-handling

```py
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  for i in lst:
    if i%2==0:
      lst.remove(i)
    else:
      break
  return lst
```

The given code produces unexpected results, but I'm not able to figure out from the output where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're suppressing items of a list your for-loop is iterating on.  Hence it suppresses half of your items.  For instance if you call your function on list `[2, 2, 4, 6, 1]` it will delete the first 2 of your list then move to `lst[1]` which is 4 (after deletion of the first 2), delete this one then move to `lst[2]` which is now 1 and terminates.  The resulting list will be `[2, 6, 1]`

It is very bad practice to modify the structure you are iterating on.  Here you should prefer a `while` loop:

```py
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
    while len(lst) > 0 and lst[0]%2==0:
        lst.remove(lst[0])
    return lst

l = [2, 2, 4, 6, 1]
delete_starting_evens(l)
print(l)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help